# Pass by reference for pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to understand the concept of passing by reference. When I do this,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int recent (int *a)
{
    *a = 20;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
   int bee;
   bee=5;
   int *val = &bee;
   printf("Value is %d\n", *val);
   recent(val);
   printf("Now Value is %d\n", *val);
   return 0;
}
```

Basically I am making the pointer `val` point to the memory location of `bee`, and then when I pass it to recent function, and change the value, that change gets reflected in the calling function, so the value changes to `20`. But when I do this,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check = 20;

int recent (int *a)
{
    a = &check;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
   int bee;
   bee=5;
   int *val = NULL;
   recent(val);
   printf("Now Value is %d\n", *val);
   return 0;
}
```

I get segmentation fault.

> Is it because I didn't initialize the pointer to point to any location, and then I passed the value to recent function, and even though I made it point to a memory location (check variable), the calling function didnt catch that because I was passing by value?

Is this completely true or I misinterpreted something and got lucky with the answer?

Comment: It's explained here: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html The function call doesn't affect the caller.

Comment: You made _the copy of the pointer_ that exists in `recent` point to `check`.

Comment: `a = &check;` changes the local copy of `a`, not the `val` in `main()`.

Comment: Wrong. You passed a pointer to int. The function received a copy of the pointer to int. Since both the original pointer to int and the copy are pointing to the same address, you can change the content of the address they point to. However, in your second code, you attempted to point the copy to the address of `check`. This itself didn't cause segmentation. What caused segmentation failure is the dereference of `*val` in printf which is still pointing to NULL.

Comment: In C you always pass by value. In your case you pass a pointer by value. Modifying that local copy won't change anything on the call side.

Comment: In the second case, the equivalent would be `int recent(int **a)` and calling with `recent(&val);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are printing the output of dereferencing the pointer val in the main function.  The value of the pointer val in the main function is NULL.  Thus the program is trying to print the thing at memory location 0, which is inaccessible to your program and results in a segmentation fault.

First you create the val pointer and assign it the value NULL.

> int *val = NULL;

Then you call recent, passing it the pointer val, which still holds NULL.

> recent(val);

Finally you print *val.  val still holds NULL, and the * operator tells the compiler to "dereference" val, meaning to use the value of the thing that val is pointing to.

> printf("Now Value is %d\n", *val);

In response to the question of whether your description is correct, the answer is sort of, but your description is imprecise.  You made the function's copy of the pointer point to something.  When you implement a pass-by-reference function in C using pointers, you are still passing the pointers themselves by value: a copy of the pointer is made, pushed onto the stack, and sent to the function.  If you update the value of the pointer in the called function, the value of the pointer in the calling function will not be changed.

Comment: I know what the problem is and I explained my understanding. I was asking if my understanding is correct

Comment: I think you meant to say if I update the address of the pointer in the called function, it wont change and would still point to same address. I can change the value it has, but not the value it points to. Right?

Comment: No, that's not precise.  It's very important to distinguish between the *value* of things and the *addresses* of things.  You cannot update the address of the pointer in the called function.  It's not possible, because it is a function parameter, and therefore it is located on the stack.  If you change the *value* of that parameter on the stack, it will not affect the value of the val pointer that was copied onto that spot.

Comment: So if the pointer that is passed to the function points to something, you can change the thing it points to by dereferencing the pointer, but the calling function has no way to know if you change the value of the function's copy of the pointer.

Comment: Yes we are on the same page, just that I didnt describe it well in my last comment. Was clarifying that only. Thanks. I liked your explanation more than the others I saw, so I accepted.

Answer (score 1):

val is still a null pointer after leaving the function. The pointer itself is (as you correctly guessed) only passed by value, not by reference. Inside the function you are only modifying the pointer (which only lives insides the function), not the pointer target.

Besides that, please be careful with passing around memory locations to automatic stack variables. At least coming from a C++ background, it's considered bad style. Since you don't explicitly control the life cycle of a stack variable yourself (as you would do with malloc/free), you can easily shoot yourself in the foot by accidentally dereferencing pointers which have already been cleaned from the stack.

Comment: References to stack variables are completely fine in C++. In fact, you do this almost all of the time (copy constructors, operators, ...)

Comment: Passing directly by reference (perfectly fine) is something else than saving the memory location in a pointer variable and passing it around freely (dangerous).

Answer (score 1):

The reason has to do with your function recent().  When you pass in "a" you are passing in an int* (i.e. int pointer) which is an address to a location in memory.  However, "a" as you have it, is local to this function (the pointer is pass by value).

Thus when you set "a = &check", you are only changing the local pointer value.  As soon as recent() returns, "a" goes out of scope. In this context, you are never changing what "a" actually points to.

Thus, you segfault because val is still null, and you are trying to dereference a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because I didn't initialize the pointer to point to any location,

Code well initialized with `int *val = NULL;`, yet `NULL` is not a *valid* location.  It isn't the `NULL` is a location or not.  It is the `NULL` is the *null pointer constant*.  As a *null pointer*, it "is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function."

> ...  and even though I made it point to a memory location (check variable), the calling function didn't catch that because I was passing by value?

Yes.  With `a = &check;`, only the local `a` was affected, not the `val` in which `a` was copied from as the *actual augment* `val` was passed by value (copied) to the *formal parameter* `a`.

> Is this completely true ...

IMO: Yes

> ...  I misinterpreted something and got lucky with the answer?

It appears no misinterpretation.  Lucky - hard to rate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is going on in your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check = 20;

int recent (int *a)
{
    a = &check;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
   // memory is allocated to hold an integer
   int bee;

   // the number 5 is written into that memory space
   bee = 5; 

   // memory is allocated to hold a memory address
   // the value of null (which is a invalid address) is written into it
   int *val = NULL;

   // more memory is allocated to hold a memory address (int* a)
   // the address in val (which is null) is written into it
   // the new memory address (a) now points to the address of check
   recent(val);

   // val is still NULL
   // BOOOM!
   printf("Now Value is %d\n", *val);

   return 0;
}
```

Long story short, you are correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's basically what all have answered. It's because you are passing the address pointed by pointer `a` using `Pass By Value` method. That is your sending in a copy of the address. If you want the second code to work you need to change the code to the following,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check = 20;

int recent(int **a)
{
   *a = &check;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
  int bee;
  bee = 5;
  int *val = NULL;
  recent(&val);
  printf("Now Value is %d\n", *val);

  return 0;
}
```

That is you have to Pass the address pointed by `a` by using C version of "Pass By Reference".